# PHP same functionality in Class throws warning

Tags: php

I am trying to count an array from within a class in PHP but I get a "Countable" error. The same thing outsite a class is working as expected.

The non-class working code is this one.

```
$numbers = array(
    array(0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,4,4,7,7,3,3,3,3,8,5,5,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,8,7,7,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,6,6,5,5,5,5,8,7,7,7,7,5,5,5,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,8,4,4,4,2,2,6,6),
    array(0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,1,1,6,6,6,3,3,3,3,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,7,7,8,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,7,7,8,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,2,2,2,2,8,7,7,7),
    array(6,6,6,3,3,3,3,8,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,4,4,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,1,1,1,8,2,2,2,2,9,9,9,9,9,4,4,4,4),
    array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,9,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,8,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,9,9,9,9,9,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
    array(0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,7,7,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,3,3,3)
);

function myFunc() {
  global $numbers;
  for ($number = 0; $number < count($numbers); $number++) {
    var_dump($numbers[$number]);
  }
}

myFunc();
```

The non-working in-class code is this one, which throws a **PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in HelloWorld.php on line 13** (Line 12 in the example below, due to php tag missing)

```
class MyClass {
  public $numbers = array(
      array(0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,4,4,7,7,3,3,3,3,8,5,5,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,8,7,7,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,6,6,5,5,5,5,8,7,7,7,7,5,5,5,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,8,4,4,4,2,2,6,6),
      array(0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,1,1,6,6,6,3,3,3,3,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,7,7,8,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,8,7,7,7,8,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,2,2,2,2,8,7,7,7),
      array(6,6,6,3,3,3,3,8,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,4,4,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,1,1,1,8,2,2,2,2,9,9,9,9,9,4,4,4,4),
      array(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,9,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,8,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,9,9,9,9,9,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5),
      array(0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,7,7,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,6,6,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,3,3,3)
  );
  
  public function myFunc() {
    global $numbers;
    for ($number = 0; $number < count($numbers); $number++) {
      var_dump($numbers[$number]);
    }
  }
}

$testMyClass = New MyClass;
$testMyClass->myFunc();
```

EDIT: I did a **gettype()** against **$numbers** and I get NULL, but I still don't understand why.

Comment: Changing`global $numbers;` with `$numbers = $this->numbers;` will do the trick. `global` is not the right way to access the defined class variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting my comment as an answer in order to close the ticket:

Changing `global $numbers;` with `$numbers = $this->numbers;` will do the trick. `global` is not the right way to access the defined class variables.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @mitkosoft, **changing global with $this->** did the trick.

Thank you!